# Creating multiple select dropdown with a submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Right now I am able to only select one item from a dropdown which passes a function onchange that displays data from a query. I would like to create a dropdown which has the capability to select multiple options then a submit button to query these options from an API. Here is my code.

Right now it can only query one value due to how HTML select works:

```
<select multiple id="selectButton" onchange="showProcessor(this.value)"></select>
```

`showProcessor` queries the value from the dropdown. What I would like is for the dropdown to have the ability to select multiple values then a button to submit those values to the API instead of using `onchange`

This is the fucntion(im using d3.js)

```
function showProcessor(str) {
    d3.json("http://localhost:3001/api/v2/monitoring/SANDBOX2/d3_ui_bar_metrics?proc_name=" + str)
}
```

So basically, the `str` is `this.value`. I would instead like str to be able to use multiple values from the dropdown multiple select

What I tried:

```
<form onchange=showProcessor(this.value)>
        <select multiple id="selectButton"></select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

This does not work as intended.

Any suggestions usin jquery as well are welcomed

Comment: That's smply not the purpose of `select` element. Use `input` element with the same `name` attribute or `checkboxes`  instead.

Answer (score 0):

check this out may it will help you!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#optionForm").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedOptions = [];
        $("#options :selected").each(function () {
            selectedOptions.push(this.value);
        });
        if (selectedOptions.length > 0) {
            alert(
                "http://localhost:3001/api/v2/monitoring/SANDBOX2/d3_ui_bar_metrics?proc_name=" +
                    encodeURIComponent(selectedOptions)
            );
            // d3.json(
            //  "http://localhost:3001/api/v2/monitoring/SANDBOX2/d3_ui_bar_metrics?proc_name=" +
            //      encodeURIComponent(selectedOptions)
            // );
        }
    });
});
```

```css
label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

button,
select {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<form id="optionForm">
    <label for="options">Choose your options:</label>
    <br><br>
    <select id="options" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="op1">op1</option>
        <option value="op2">op2</option>
        <option value="op3">op3</option>
        <option value="op4">op4</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```